# Question on dimensions

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

It is well known that a line has **2** points.

A square has **4** lines.

A cube has **6** squares.

A tesseract has **8** cubes.

And continuing there will be 10, 12, 14, etc.

Why does the sequence increase by 2? I can figure out why the number of points in each case is always $2^N$ (because you are doubling the points in each instance), but can't figure out why in each dimension N the number of (N-1) dimension figures used is 2n.

Comment: It follows from the Euler characteristic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Comment: In what way does it follow?

Comment: See my answer.${}$

Comment: See this [29 August 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/W_WDXmUxNGU/m/ZaL7VJc9hfgJ) for a proof that the number of $k$-cubes that bound an $n$-cube is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(x+2)^n.$ The result you're interested in is when $k$ is equal to $n-1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:** See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube. This says that

> A hypercube of dimension n has 2n sides (a 1-dimensional line has 2 end points; a 2-dimensional square has 4 sides or edges; a 3-dimensional cube has 6 2-dimensional faces; a 4-dimensional tesseract has 8 cells). The number of vertices (points) of a hypercube is $2^{n}$.

Why?

Consider the $n$-dimension hypercube with vertices at $(\pm x,\pm x,\ldots,\pm x)$. Its volume $V_n(x)$ is $(2x)^n$. Expand the hypercube a little bit from $x$ to $x + \epsilon$, each $m$-dimension face of the hypercube will contribute an extra hypervolume $V_m(x) \epsilon^{n-m}$ to the new hypercube. This means:

$$V_{n}(x+\epsilon) = \sum_{m=0}^n N_{n,m} V_{m}(x)\epsilon^{n-m}$$
where $N_{n,m}$ is the number of $m$-dimension "faces" of a $n$-dimension hypercube.

One the other hand, binomial theorem tell us:

$$V_n(x+\epsilon) = 2^n(x+\epsilon)^n = 2^n\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} x^{m} \epsilon^{n-m}
=\sum_{m=0}^n 2^{n-m}\epsilon{n}{m}V_{m}(x)\epsilon^{n-m}
$$

By comparing the coefficients of powers in $\epsilon$, we immediately get:

$$\boxed{N_{n,m} = 2^{n-m} \binom{n}{m}}$$

**Method 2:** It follows from the Euler characteristic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Let $b_n$ be the $n$-th Betti number, i.e., the rank of the $n$-th singular homology group.
Then, the Euler characteristic is
$$\chi=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^nb_n$$
Thus, use Euler's formula:
$$F=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-1)^nb_n+\text{number of edges $-$ number of vertices}$$

Comment: In method 1 I got how you used binomial theorem to find the volume but I did not get how you got the equation "each m-dimension face of the hypercube will contribute an extra hypervolume Vm(x)ϵn−m" and the equation under that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Think about it in one dimension, and then two, and then imagine it in three. This will show you your result.